# creating a cost function with different level of variable cost.

Tags: functions, linear-transformations

To generate cost function from given information, variable cost is used as independent variables, if the variable cost changes with different level of output, how can I generate a cost function from that?

For instance, if the fixed cost is **500** and variable cost is **3** for first **300** unit and **2.5** for any unit produced *after* the first **300**, what would be the cost function in this scenario?

Comment: you can write it piecewise, e.g. for units$\leq 300$ and units $>300$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write these functions as piecewise functions:
Cost: $C(x) =   
\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
      500 + 3x & x\leq 300 \\
      500 + 900 + 2.5(x-300) & x > 300 \\
\end{array} 
\right. $

Comment: Great. Thanks a lot.